# Java secure scripting

Tags: javascript, java, groovy, scripting, sandbox

I want to receive String with script and list of arguments. Then invoke this script with specified parameters and receive result. What is important I have to execute this script with no trust. I want to:

- Make restriction on CPU time for script (e.g. while(true) {})
- Make restriction on memory for script (e.g. filling up huge array)
- Restrict access to any Java classes from script code (e.g. Thread)
- Restrict access to JVM (e.g. System.exit(1))
- Restrict access to network
- Restrict access to file system

I would like to use JavaScript or Groovy in this matter. Until now I have tried few sandboxes but unfortunately none of them offered what I need. Do you have any suggestions which library can evaluate untrusted script in the safe environment? 
Thanks.

Comment: Groovy, when impelment quite sophisticated MyGroovyLoader can control 3 (and consequently io/net classes 5 &6 ). Loader can analyze package / class name and allow / deny.

Comment: In C world Lua can have high control (modules can be eliminated). I have never saw CPU limits in scripting engines (1)

Comment: Few Docker evangelist promise such features, but this is solution at totally difeerent layer.

Comment: javadelight:delight-nashorn-sandbox allows to restrict CPU time and access to Java classes but it doesn't allow to make memory restrictions.

Comment: "Recommend a tool" questions are off-topic on SO, so your question will most likely get closed soon. Besides that, we use http://groovy-sandbox.kohsuke.org/ to Sandbox Groovy code entered by the user of the application. You can easily resrict access to classes and JVM. Not sure about the other things.